# Best way to see a EkReminder recurrence frequency?

Tags: ios, swift, recurrence, ekeventstore

When loading a reminder from the EKEventStore, what is the best way to determine what type of recurrence frequency the reminder has?

So far I have been able to see if the reminder contains a recurrenceRule using:

```
if reminder.hasRecurrenceRules {
  if true {
    print("Reminder has recurrence rule")
  }
}
```

But as this only returns a boolean. I was wondering how best I can return a reminders recurrence frequency (i.e. if the recurrence rule is .daily or .weekly). Do I need to use a different method and if so, how?

I’m a complete rookie at this so I hope some of this makes sense, I could be completely off the ball…

I really appreciate any help and guidance! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `EKCalendarItem` has an array of recurrence rules `recurrenceRules`, instances of [EKRecurrenceRule](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKRecurrenceRuleClassRef/)

Therefore, you can check for example:

```
if let recurrenceRule = reminder.recurrenceRules.first {
   if recurrenceRule.frequence == .daily {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sulthan for your help! It is now all working! I really appreciate it!  Thanks.